# Plotting in Python Notebook (Docs)

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Attempting to go through the pandas doc at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot I get an error :

```
NameError: name 'Series' is not defined
```

I can import pandas and supply 'pandas.Series', but I want to know how to set up notebook, as in the docs, so that it's already included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize Ipython notebook profile file **ipython_config.py** typically  located in ~/.ipython/profile_default/ by adding something like :

```python
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import pandas',
]
```

You can read the documentation for ipython latest version [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html)

Comment: What type of file should this be? Or do I add it to an existing file in .../profile_default ?

Comment: Usually in  your home, in a .ipython/profile_default directory

Comment: Thanks, I've found the file. Now I'm going to figure out how to use 'Series' without saying 'pandas.Series' , but I'm sure that will be easy to find.